error: you need to load the kernel first - 24.04 LTS
I tried a couple of different solutions including these ones, but nothing seems to work. This is the third time this happened to this laptop, and it always happens when I hard reboot. The first two times my battery drained and I had to install a clean new Ubuntu instance.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...

I get to the boot menu, and I try starting Ubuntu but it just navigates to the error screen above. I also tried rebooting from the grub console a couple of times as some people encountering the same problem said that it helps, but for me it did nothing.

I also tried running other version and in recovery, and running the old version I can get to the decryption screen but it again shuts down and goes to the boot screen.

I also tried running fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv -y and it fixes the broken inodes, but again, after finishing it just reboots to the grub loader.
EDIT: Here is the boot entry:
setparams Ubuntu

recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ xsgrub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod Izopio; f1
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ee30291e-efe4-4ff7-6776-38240ce9ab19
linux /vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd /initrd. img-6.8.0-48-generic

EDIT2:
In advanced options I have the following:
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-48-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-47-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-47-generic (recovery mode)

The *47 version is the one that goes all the way to the encryption loader screen (Lenovo) but it never recovers, and it just straight up reboots.
EDIT3:
These are my grub set variables:
grub> set
?='0'
check_signatures= 'no
color_highlight='black/light-gray
color_normal='light-gray/black
config_directory='(hdo,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu
config_file='(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
default='0'
feature_200_final='y'
festure_all_video_module-'y'
feature_chainloader_bpb='y
feature_default_font_path='y
feature_ feature. menuentry_id= menuentry_options= y' g
feature_nativedisk_cmd='y'
feature_ntldr='y'
feature_platform_search_hint='y
feature_timeout_style='y
font='unicode
fw_path='(hdo,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu'
gfxmode='auto
grub_cpu='x86_64'
grub_netfs_type='grub
grub_platform='efi'
have_grubenv='true
lang='en_US
linux_gfx_mode='text'
locale_dir=' (hdø,gpt2)/grub/locale
menu_color_highlight='black/light-gray
menu_color_normal='white/black
menuentry_Id_opt lon="-Iid"
net_default_ip=
net_default_mac='
net_default_server='
package_version='2.12-1ubuntu7
pager=' -
preflx=' (hd0,gpt2)/grub
pxe_default_server=
recordfail='1'
root='hdø,gpt2'
secondary_locale_dir=

Thank you for all the help!

Press e to edit the boot entry for Ubuntu.   Don't post a picture.  Write it all out using triple tick marks as the markdown.

@eyoung100
hello, I provided the boot entry in the question

The boot entry looks complete to me.  The LVM is enabled as it's pointing to a Volume Group. See grub error: you need to load kernel first.  Since the entry is proper, is Secure boot on or off?  See AKMalkadis answer.  This is one you linked to, but did you read or try all the answers? For example, a kernel compiled to use grubs secure shim will not boot if secure boot is off, and vice versa

@eyoung100 thanks for the answer!
Secure boot is/was turned off the whole time, I did try to enable it to check whether it would boot, but no avail. I did turn it off via BIOS, because  AKMaldi's command didn't work (unknown command),
I did also tried with GAD3R answer (some of the boot params were different but I managed to set it up), still nothing.
